# Recovering from Redis::TimeoutError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis

I'm experiencing this error with my app on the Heroku recently. And found this bit :

```
My::Application.config.session_store :redis_session_store, {
  # ... other options ...
  on_redis_down: ->(e, env, sid) { do_something_will_ya!(e) }
  redis: {
    # ... redis options ...
  }
}
```

On the gem github page. So my question is, what do I pass in this block and how do I communicate the error back to the user. How is this done in general I mean?

Do I raise an exception than catch it in my application controller and do something or? I really have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

For handling the error you have some choices that are based on your architecture.

First the most important thing is to make sure you are logging the issue so you can track down the culprit.

Second, I am not sure on your usage of redis. But if redis is required for your site to function, then you are essentially down and should communicate that to your users AND to your support/operations/development/self.

If you are using redis as a cache mechanism, but can read from the database, then that is a fairly straightforward fix for the situation, however it does not sound like this is your situation.

Fixing the error:
Generally, with a redis timeout error or any timeout error it is indicative of a larger problem. For example, are you sending lots of individual commands to redis as opposed to piping in the commands in bulk?

You could do a retry mechanism, but on timeout errors that generally means your site is not going to be responsive to users if it is UI/Interface related actions.